# #include<opencv2/opencv.hpp> // Fatal error, no such file or directory, when using mingw-w64-x86_64-opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, visual-studio-code, mingw-w64, msys2

I'm new to using C++ compilers as well as opencv. I'm using mingw's MSYS2 as my compiler, and I have got it working with VSC as my ide to compile some c++ code. However, when I try to include opencv libraries I get the fatal error that the file path can't be found.

I installed mingw's opencv package: mingw-w64-x86_64-opencv, and I added C:\msys64\mingw64\include\opencv4 to my system PATH, however on VSC when I include an opencv library I get this:
[script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MK9G.png) [terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vim35.png)

What's the problem and its solution?

Comment: show your [c_cpp_properties.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) and the configuration for whatever you are using to build the program. Ex. a commandline command(s), tasks.json file, a build script, or CMake config.

Comment: *"added C:\msys64\mingw64\include\opencv4 to my system PATH"* This is wrong, and probably has no effect. PATH is only for executables.

Comment: What does `which gcc` say?